# How can I delay "onsubmit" event until something is loaded?

Tags: javascript, events, delay, onsubmit

I have problem that in `onSubmit` event of a `form`.

I am sending some tracking information to another webpage using javascript `image` element for that (parameters are in `GET`).

But when I try to load that `image` (via `src` attribute), page is refreshed sooner than the request for `image` takes place (or is immediately aborted).

This way, no information is sent to external tracking page. How can I wait in this `submit` handler for `load` of that `image`?

**EDIT:**
There is one more point I missed, that other events can be in the same place (e.g. validation etc.)

Comment: use a synchronous [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: @sabithpocker: no this needs to be plain JS (for compatibility with more pages)

Comment: @Yoshi: synchronous request can be solution if I can handle timeouts

Comment: @sabithpocker: the is cross-domain issue in IE, since it is sent to external domain name, do you have any clue how to solve this?

Comment: @XaReSx Why havent you still added the relevant code you have. Add your `submit event listener` and the `code` you are using `for tracking`. These guys came with such wonderful answers even without that :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image'),
    form = document.getElementById('form');

img.addEventListener('load', function (){
    window.imageIsLoaded = true;
    if(window.submitForm === true){
        form.submit();
    }
}, false);

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e){
    window.submitForm = true;
    if(window.imageIsLoaded !== true){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}, false);​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/nATYk/)

Comment: I'm afraid this will just cancell submit event. And will force user to click submit button twice

Comment: The problem with your edit is, that practically all browsers will capture the newly submitted form (if the target anything that will open a new window/tab) in the popup-blocker.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to auto-submit the form if required without the use of globals:

```
document.getElementById('yourFrm').addEventListener('submit',(function()
{
    'use strict';
    var imgLoaded,img,tmpImgLoad;
    imgLoaded = false;
    img = document.getElementById('yourImg');
    tmpImgLoad = function ()
    {
        imgLoaded = true;
        img.removeEventListener('load',tmpImgLoad,false);//remove obsolete listener?
    };
    img.addEventListener('load',tmpImgLoad,false);
    return function(e)
    {
        if (!imgLoaded)
        {
            tmpImgLoad = function()
            {
                imgLoaded = true;
                img.removeEventListener('load',tmpImgLoad,false);
                document.getElementById('yourForm').submit();
            };
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    };
})(),false);
```

This code binds a load event listener to your image element, that sets a closure variable to true. If that variable is false when the form is submitted, the callback for the load event is altered to submit the form, too.

I will admit this is a tad more complex, but just so you know: globals are not the only way to tackle this problem.

*Just passed the lot through JSLint, too. A couple of tiny adjustments and with "tolerate messy white-space" and "asume browser" this code passes without any warnings or errors at all*

Comment: To me the question seems to be: how to load that tracking-image while submitting. Your solution assumes the given image is part of the dom already. I don't think that this is correct.

Comment: @Yoshi, I sort of assumed it was part of the dom already because of the answer provided by Amaan and the question: _But when I try to load that image (via src attribute)_. But if this weren't the case, then you're right, of course and the OP should turn to ajax for the easiest solution to his problem.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: great, but i did not mentioned there can be other submit events in place (see my last edit), so I personally think I can't prevent submit and propagation.

Comment: stopping the event from propagation shouldn't be an issue, as long as you attach the event listener to the one particular form that shouldn't be submitted unless the img is loaded. If that's what you mean, of course. If you want to go ahead and validate this form even though that img isn't fully loaded, then leaving out `stopPropagation` allows for form validation, without the form being submitted. So yes, just remove the `stopPropagation()`, but on the whole the code will still work as expected